# How to click first link in an overlay using selenium driver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to build a simple app to learn Selenium in Python using a custom google search url to search Reddit and scrape the results:
https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=011171116424399119392:skuhhpapys8

I am trying to click on the first link in the overlay that comes up after a search on the site as pictured here

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GutGr.png)

I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=011171116424399119392:skuhhpapys8"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gsc-search-button')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("gsc-i-id1")

soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

search = input("Ask Reddit")
inputElement.send_keys(search)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

overlay = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gsc-results-wrapper-overlay')

first_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.gsc-title').click()
```

and I get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: a.gsc-title
```

Any idea on what I am missing? Is there something special I have to do to deal with an overlay like that? There are multiple elements by that css selector am I not targeting the first?

Comment: Just at a quick glance, chances are you need to "activate" the iframe before trying to click it.

Comment: something like this?
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")))

Comment: yea something like that

Answer (score 1):

The class for a link, as far as I can see is **not** `gsc-title`, it's `gs-title`. Hence your main problem. But also a couple of other things:

1. There's nothing special about overlay, no need to account for it. So `overlay = driver.<...>` is not required, unless you use it to make sure results showed up (see next point)
2. Changing implicit wait (`driver.implicitly_wait(30)`) is not a good idea; use explicit wait instead:

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   ...
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "gsc-results-wrapper-overlay")))
   first_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.gs-title').click()
   ```

Comment: thanks, looking more into it there seems to be an iframe within the overlay. would i need to switch to that iframe before trying to click the first link?

Comment: @ron_kuby you don't have to switch to iframe if your element is not inside iframe. In your particular case the element is not inside any iframe. but I have tested with other inputs, and the first link can be also inside an iframe

Comment: based on example provided, the link is not inside iframe, but @AndreiSuvorkov says it might be for other inputs. So potentially your script needs to handle both situations